# Two knots with same Dowker-Thistlethwaite code have isomorphic knot groups?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

Given a (tame) knot diagram, one derives the Dowker-Thistlethwaite code by travelling around the knot  and numbering each crossing 1,2,3,.... A negative sign is given to an even number if you cross on an underpass with that even number. Each crossing gets an even-odd pair of numbers, and we sort the pairs by the odd numbers. The resulting even number sequence is the Dowker-Thistlethwaite code of the knot.

This code determines a prime knot uniquely but there may be multiple composite knots with the same code.

> **Question**: Given any two knots with the same Dowker-Thistlethwaite code, are their knot groups isomorphic?

I believe the answer is yes because of the comment on Wikipedia that two knots with the same code will be almost the same except for a reflection or a reflection of the way the connected sum is taken in a prime knot decomposition. Therefore one can define an isomorphism of fundamental groups easily enough. However there does not seem to be a reference for this fact either, and Dowker and Thistlethwaite (at least to me) don't seem to talk about this in their paper [1]. However, I'm mainly an algebraist and my algebraic topology expertise is not as thorough as I'd like, so I would appreciate some help.

[1] Dowker, C. H.; Thistlethwaite, Morwen B. Classification of knot projections. Topology Appl. 16 (1983), no. 1, 19--31. MR0702617

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.  The DT code gives a composite *diagram* if and only if the permutation splits into two sub-permutations.  So, if the code does not split, then it specifies a prime *diagram* which we can reconstruct up to taking a mirror image.

This is discussed (briefly) in Section 2.2 of "The Knot Book" by Colin Adams.

Comment: This does not answer my question. I already know that with prime knots, the answer is "yes". My question was: given any two knots with the same code (composite OR prime), are their **knot groups** isomorphic? The point of this question is for the case when the knots are not prime.

Comment: As I said, you are correct and the primeness of the knot is not relevant, only the primeness of the diagram.  Again. If the code does not split then we can reconstruct the prime diagram and get the correct knot complement. If the code does split, then the diagram does as well.  So there is a splitting annulus that decomposes the group in the desired fashion.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I understand that. Is there a reference beyond Adams' book? In it he doesn't actually provide a proof of this fact.

Comment: I do not know a reference for what you ask.  Theorem 1 of the Dowker-Thistlethwaite paper deals with the "non-split" case and you can assemble a proof from that.  Perhaps Jeff Erickson or Ben Burton know of a better reference for this.